# How to setChecked true Checkbox from API response in recycler view

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview

Here I want to set Checked true checkbox getting value from API response in recycler view 
There are multiple values of checkbox in response 
For example
When a user registers in-app there some checkbox dynamics that values are saved in database.
while editing profile same checkbox will be there but need to set Checked true from API response

There are 2 different API's
1 Getting all values of Edit Profile (in which also getting the value of checkbox as comma separated) 
2 Checkbox Dynamic values

Here is Dynamic checkbox values adapter

```
 public class CarrierCustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CarrierCustomAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

        private ArrayList<ResultCarriersAndOccupation> moviesList;

        public CarrierCustomAdapter(ArrayList<ResultCarriersAndOccupation> moviesList) {
            this.moviesList = moviesList;
        }

        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.item_carrier_and_occupations, parent, false);

            return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
        }

        public void clear() {
            int size = this.moviesList.size();
            if (size > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    this.moviesList.remove(0);
                }

                this.notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, size);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {


            final ResultCarriersAndOccupation datum = moviesList.get(position);
            holder.cb_carrier_occupation.setText(datum.getName() + "");

            holder.cb_carrier_occupation.setTag(moviesList.get(position));




            holder.cb_carrier_occupation.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {





                }
            });


        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return moviesList.size();
        }

        public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            AppCompatCheckBox cb_carrier_occupation;

            public MyViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);


                cb_carrier_occupation = view.findViewById(R.id.cb_carrier_occupation);


            }

        }

    }
```

API Response of EditProfile

Model class ResultCarriersAndOccupation

```
public class ResultCarriersAndOccupation {

    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

here is the response of EditProfile APIin JSON

```
  {
    "error": false,
    "msg": "Success",
    "result_user_all_info": {
        "user_id": "2",
        "username": "Fazal",
        "surname": "Sandhi",
        "email": "sandhi.faiz@gmail.com",
        "phone": "9737676689",
        "phone_2": "",
        "line_id": "",
        "address1": "Palej",
        "address2": "Mesrad",
        "city": "Vadodara",
        "zip": "",
        "langlat": "",
        "password": "40bd001563085fc35165329ea1ff5c5ecbdbbeef",
        "fb_id": null,
        "g_id": null,
        "g_photo": null,
        "creation_date": "1564054305",
        "google_plus": null,
        "skype": null,
        "facebook": null,
        "wishlist": "[\"164\",\"166\",\"128\",\"128\",\"109\",\"156\",\"167\",\"114\",\"114\",\"142\",\"142\",\"567\",\"422\"]",
        "last_login": "1580967064",
        "user_type": "default",
        "user_type_till": null,
        "left_product_type": "[]",
        "downloads": "[]",
        "country": "India",
        "state": "Gujarat",
        "wallet": "NDM1My45",
        "m_point": "Nzcx",
        "product_upload": "2",
        "package_info": "[]",
        "id_card_number": "90980201",
        "dob": "29-09-2019",
        "carriers_and_occupations": "Goverment",
        "how_do_u_find_us": "Friend,Facebook,Youtube,Google,Bill Board,Magazine",
        "buy_purpose": "For Sale",
        "gender": "Male"
    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot in which I want to set checked checkbox  true of How do you find us in recycler view

[image: How do you find us]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please share your code and state clearly what you want to achieve

Comment: dear code added

Comment: You can do that in onBindViewHolder() method, when you have true item in list then you can checkbox.setChecked() = true

Comment: geting string not boolean

Comment: You can put condition for checking string if string is true than checkBox.setChecked(true) else do nothing

Comment: Otherwise share code of your model class : ResultCarriersAndOccupation, I will provide the solution

Comment: added in code pls check it

Comment: Where do you get values for setting check box true or false? Its not there in your model

Comment: I already told you getting string in response of edit profile api not Boolean

Comment: You're not understanding what i'm asking

Comment: Api response added in code 

in that How do you find us  are values of checkbox that i need to setchecked true

Comment: are you there @KaranMehta

Answer (score 2):

you must do something step by steps:

1.you must get numbers of words with counting "," in your json value.

2.split your string in an arraylist (in this example its array list with 5 string value)

3.now in a for loop, you must check string in arrays with a switch case.

4.every string in that array will go in a switch case with all of you got there and in each case you can setchecked check boxes

update me in comments ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a model for your UI layer not using the direct serialized model from the API call. 
 
also, You have to define an interface for holding your set of constants like **how_do_u_find_us**

```
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
@IntDef({Method.FACEBOOK, Method.TWITTER, Method.GOOGLE})
public @interface Method {
    int FACEBOOK = 1;
    int TWITTER = 2;
    int GOOGLE = 3;
}
```

you have map every possible returned string to a constant variable
like if Facebook, twitter is returned you have to split it and check for every single value to map it

```
class Mapper{
        public POJO map(){
            @Method
            List<Integer> methodsConstantsList = new ArrayList<>();

            String methods = "facebook, twitter";
            String [] methodsList = methods.split(",");
            for (String x: methodsList){
                if (x.equals("facebook")){
                    methodsConstantsList.add(Method.FACEBOOK);
                }else if (x.equals("twitter")){
                    methodsConstantsList.add(Method.TWITTER);
                }
            }
            return new POJO(methodsConstantsList);

        }
    }
```

so your model will be

```
public class POJO {

    @Method
    private List<Integer> methods;

    public POJO(List<Integer> methods){
        this.methods = methods;
    }

    public void setMethods(List<Integer> methods) {
        this.methods = methods;
    }

    public void add(){
        this.methods.add(Method.GOOGLE);
    }
}
```

and then in your view holder, you have to check the list of values you have to set checkbox is checked to true